# Can I renegotiate an offer I already said was okay?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, salary, job-offer, unprofessional-behavior

I had a meeting (after passing the knowledge interview and another meeting) with a software company for which I would like to work.

When it came down to money, they asked me how I feel about X salary. I said it sounded ok, and at the end I received an offer and they gave me time to think about it.

If now I feel different about the salary, is it appropriate to renegotiate it? (I would like a higher wage)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If now I feel different about the sum, it is appropriate to bring it
>   back to discussing?( that I would like a higher wage)

Since you were given time to think about it, it's reasonable to indicate that after thinking about it you have decided that you would like a higher wage.

You have weakened your position and made negotiation more difficult by already indicating that the offered salary was "okay". (Since you used the word "renegotiate" in the question title, it seems that you understand this.) You have signaled a tentative acceptance, and now you are undoing that. But you can still ask for more.

Be prepared to discuss *why* you think you are worth more. Don't just indicate that you want more. Consider the entire offer package - salary, benefits, work environment, growth potential, other offers, etc. And consider the entirety of what is involved with the job - the tasks, the hours, the overtime, the on-call, etc.

Also be prepared if the company believes that their offer was fair and declines to offer more. Decide ahead of time how you will respond.

Next time when asked about an offer, be less definitive. Instead of saying that it is "okay", say something like "Well, it's less than I was expecting. I'll have to think it over."

Saying "it sounded okay" may cause the company to harden their position, believing that you will be willing to accept the offer. Being less definitive may cause them to think about how much they will bend to meet an expected counteroffer.

Comment: Agreed. They sound as though they did everything correct and so did you. It is always best for the company to say what they pay instead of asking what you want, but they accepted. With nothing changed you don't want to make changes, accept or decline. If you decline because the pay is too low well who's fault is that. Be decisive. Had you asked for more they might have declined on the spot. They didn't mess around, you should not also.

Comment: Since you have not signed the offer.  You are always free to renegotiate the terms.  You just might not be successful since you indicated terms were acceptable.  They based their offer based on your original negotiation, by saying their offer was acceptable, you basically set your anchor price at that price.